# ESB with PayLoadFactory: error: java.io.IOException: Decompression of response failed

Tags: wso2, esb

I have this scenario:

I consume some information from a data service and another information from another data service and I want to merge this two information in a unique response.

In this test I don´t use the data services, I use mock services in SOAPUI and both mock services work fine separately .

The data I want to merge, an example:

Data service 1 response:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
xmlns:obt="http://informatizacion.uci.cu/servicios/assets/ObtenerPersonas">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <obt:Personas>
         <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
         <obt:Persona>
            <obt:idExpediente>T123654</obt:idExpediente>
            <obt:primerNombre>yanaka</obt:primerNombre>
            <obt:primerApellido>perez</obt:primerApellido>
            <obt:segundoApellido>perez</obt:segundoApellido>
            <obt:sexo>F</obt:sexo>
            <obt:ci>920125848</obt:ci>
            <obt:provincia>ok</obt:provincia>
            <obt:municipio>yes</obt:municipio>
            <obt:area>facultad</obt:area>
            <obt:esDocente>false</obt:esDocente>
         </obt:Persona>
      </obt:Personas>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Data service 2 response:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
xmlns:preg="http://pregrado.uci.cu">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <preg:Personas>
         <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
         <preg:Persona>
            <preg:idExpediente>11111</preg:idExpediente>
            <preg:primerNombre>jorge</preg:primerNombre>
            <preg:primerApellido>infante</preg:primerApellido>
            <preg:segundoApellido>osorio</preg:segundoApellido>
            <preg:sexo>M</preg:sexo>
            <preg:ci>1221122112211221</preg:ci>
            <preg:provincia>rdf</preg:provincia>
            <preg:municipio>dsf</preg:municipio>
            <preg:area>df</preg:area>
            <preg:esDocente>true</preg:esDocente>
         </preg:Persona>
         <preg:Persona>
            <preg:idExpediente>gero et</preg:idExpediente>
            <preg:primerNombre>sonoras imperio</preg:primerNombre>
            <preg:primerApellido>quae divum incedo</preg:primerApellido>
            <preg:segundoApellido>verrantque per auras</preg:segundoApellido>
            <preg:sexo>per auras</preg:sexo>
            <preg:ci>circum claustra</preg:ci>
            <preg:provincia>nimborum in</preg:provincia>
            <preg:municipio>foedere certo</preg:municipio>
            <preg:area>profundum quippe ferant</preg:area>
            <preg:esDocente>false</preg:esDocente>
         </preg:Persona>
      </preg:Personas>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

So I build this proxy service:

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="PersonaPoC"
transports="https,http" statistics="disable" trace="disable"
startOnLoad="true">
   <target inSequence="conf:/PersonaPoC/obtener_estudiantes"/>
   <publishWSDL key="conf:/wsdl/PersonaSimplev2.wsdl"/>
   <description></description>
</proxy>
```

With this sequences:

Name: obtener_estudiantes.

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
   <payloadFactory>
      <format>
         <preg:ObtenerEstudiantesPoC xmlns:preg="http://pregrado.uci.cu"/>
      </format>
   </payloadFactory>
   <send receive="conf:/PersonaPoC/guardar_Estudiantes">
      <endpoint>
         <address uri="http://destrono:8088/mockPregradoWSSOAP12Binding/"/>
      </endpoint>
   </send>
</sequence>
```

Name: guardar_Estudiantes.

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
   <enrich>
      <source clone="false" type="body"/>
      <target action="replace" type="property"
property="listado_estudiantes"/>
   </enrich>
   <payloadFactory>
      <format>
         <obt:ObtenerPersonasPoC
xmlns:obt="http://informatizacion.uci.cu/servicios/assets/ObtenerPersonas"/>
      </format>
   </payloadFactory>
   <log level="full"/>
   <send receive="conf:/PersonaPoC/unir_Personas">
      <endpoint>
         <address uri="http://destrono:8888/mockAssetsSOAP12Binding"/>
      </endpoint>
   </send>
</sequence>
```

At this point I see this error in the ESB when execute the service:

This is a log of the message send to the second service, mockAssetsSOAP12Binding. I don´t know why appear this namespace:
xmlns:preg=http://pregrado.uci.cu  in the request because I don´t used it in the payloadfactory mediator.

```
[2013-04-10 20:17:17,303]  INFO - LogMediator To:
http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: ,
MessageID: urn:uuid:26b0c552-d8e6-4285-8814-84c595dae544, Direction:
response, Envelope: 
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
xmlns:preg="http://pregrado.uci.cu">
      <soap:Body>
         <obt:ObtenerPersonasPoC
xmlns:obt="http://informatizacion.uci.cu/servicios/assets/ObtenerPersonas"/>
      </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The error:

```
[2013-04-10 19:49:30,472] ERROR - RelayUtils Error while building Passthrough stream
org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPProcessingException: Transport level information does not match with SOAP Message namespace URI
        at
org.apache.axis2.builder.BuilderUtil.validateSOAPVersion(BuilderUtil.java:77
4)
        at
org.apache.axis2.builder.SOAPBuilder.processDocument(SOAPBuilder.java:58)
        at
org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.DeferredMessageBuilder.getDocumen
t(DeferredMessageBuilder.java:146)
        at
org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.builldMessage(RelayUti
ls.java:150)
        at
org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtil
s.java:91)
        at
org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediat
or.java:62)
        at
org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.
java:114)
        at
org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2Syn
apseEnvironment.java:223)
        at
org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseC
allbackReceiver.java:443)
        at
org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbac
kReceiver.java:166)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at
org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:217
)
        at
org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerP
ool.java:172)
        at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:11
10)
        at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:6
03)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

when I used the data services in AS 5.1.0 I saw this error:
org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPProcessingException: First Element must contain the local name, Envelope , but found faultstring

If I put the TCPMon I can see this message exchange:

```
Incoming message:
POST /mockAssetsSOAP12Binding HTTP/1.1
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=UTF-8
Server: Jetty(6.1.x)
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Host: 127.0.0.1:8888
Connection: Keep-Alive

124
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
xmlns:preg="http://pregrado.uci.cu"><soap:Body>

   <obt:ObtenerPersonasPoC
xmlns:obt="http://informatizacion.uci.cu/servicios/assets/ObtenerPersonas"/>
</soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
0
```

Outgoing message:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: Jetty(6.1.x)

1a0
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap:Body>
    <soap:Fault>
      <soap:Code>
        <soap:Value>Server</soap:Value>
      </soap:Code>
      <soap:Reason>
        <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
        <soap:Text xml:lang="en">java.io.IOException: Decompression of response failed</soap:Text>
      </soap:Reason>
    </soap:Fault>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
0
```

This is the last sequence.
Name: unir_Personas.

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
   <enrich>
      <source clone="false" type="body"/>
      <target action=" sibling" type="property"
property="listado_estudiantes"/>
   </enrich>
   <send/>
</sequence>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

> I don´t know why appear this namespace:
>   xmlns:preg=http://pregrado.uci.cu in the request because I don´t used
>   it in the payloadfactory mediator.

You might get that from your endpoint's response. You are using payload only for body and that particular namespace appears at rootlevel. Anyway, that is not the cause for the issue you are facing. In the middle you mentioned about SOAP12 service . Check the namespace is right, and if your endpoint accepts SOAP 12 requests, change the endpoint format to soap12

Comment: yes, my endpoint accepts soap12 request, in this case allways fail the second payload factory mediator in the chaining, if I change the sequence order the firts one is ok but the second not.